# Trying to update Database addValueEventListener

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to update my database.
Something that i am doing doesn’t work. At the first time that I call this method it updates the database but finishes the activity. At the second time that I call that method it gets into an infinite loop.

```
public void savePractice(){
        //This Method saves the Practice in the Database under the Athlete practices
        currentAthleteRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                currentAthlete = dataSnapshot.getValue(Athlete.class);
                if (currentAthlete.practices == null){
                    currentAthlete.practices = new ArrayList<Practice>();
                    currentAthlete.practices.add(practice);
                }
                else {
                    currentAthlete.practices.add(practice);
                }
                currentAthleteRef.child("Practices").setValue(currentAthlete.practices);
                finish();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                showProgress("Failed to find Athlete please tell us!!!!!!");
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Please edit the question to explain what you think this code should be doing other than what you observe.  I'm seeing that you have a call to `finish()` in the callback, so I would expect this code to finish the activity as soon as it receives some data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My quick guess is that you're looking to read the data only once, and update it. That is not what your code does however: `addValueEventListener` adds a semi-permanent listener, that stays actively listening for the data until you remove it.

If you want to only read the value once, and then stop listening for change, you should use:

```
currentAthleteRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(...
```

Overall though: if the new value depends on the current value in the same database location, you should [use a transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions) to prevent concurrent updates from overwriting each other.

Comment: Thanks I will try it.